Desktop size and position on Windows 11
I am running a Windows 11 PC with an NVidia GeForce RTX 3060 connected to a Samsung 4K monitor. Both Windows and NVidia drivers are up to date. Everything was fine until now. I moved the PC to another location so had to disconnect and reconnect everything. Now, the screen is running off the monitor in all four directions (screenshot attached). Also, the highest refresh rate now showing 30 instead of 60.
I have found many recommendations on the internet and have tried every combination of settings I could think of. The equipment and software are exctly the same. There has not even been a recent update to software (Windows and Drivers).
I am totally stumped and would appreciate any advice.
UPDATE: I did not realize that the first screenshot included the overrun areas. Please refer to the third image below to see what I am seeing.




"Now, the screen is running off the monitor in all four directions" - Is not a clear description

@Ramhound. My apologies as when I took a screenshot, I did not realize it took the whole screen irrespective of what I am seeing. Please have a look at the edited portion of the question.

I see nothing odd in any of the screenshots.

Ok, so I figured out that the problem was the monitor. The HDMI port had it's PC/AV mode set to AV instead of PC. Changing that fized the issue.
